# catch search action from jQuery datatables ('bFilter')

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jQuery datatables.
But im looking for a way to react when the user starts entering something in the default search bar.

everything regarding search is working. I just need to clear any selections made in the tables, by the user.

Anyone know how to catch this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture "user starts entering something in the default search bar" with

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').keyup(function () {
    // do something, e.g. 
    console.log(arguments);
});
```